# Use DrawerNavigator and StackNavigator together

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an overview page with has an icon at the left to open the drawer. Now I want to go for a navigation from a button situated in the drawer. Now this is how I have defined the NavigationContainer.

```
const MapStack = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Overview" component={SocketMap} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
      <DrawerView.Navigator>
        <DrawerView.Screen name="WalletNew" component={walletActual} />
      </DrawerView.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const DrawerView = createDrawerNavigator();
```

But this reproduce the following error :

> Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.

Any suggestions would be appreciated for this issue.

Comment: One problem is that you have two navigators next to each other. One should be nested inside the other as a screen.

Comment: The answer I linked is about a tab navigator instead of a stack navigator, but the approach is the same. In your case the drawer navigator can be the main navigator and the stack navigator could be a screen in the drawer navigator.